# Machine Learning Model overfitting

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I build a GRU model and I'm comparing 3 different datasets on the same model. I was just running the first dataset and set the number of epochs to 25, but I have noticed that my validation loss is increasing just after the 6th epoch, doesn't that indicate overfitting, am I doing something wrong?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from google.colab import files
from tensorboardcolab import TensorBoardColab, TensorBoardColabCallback
tbc=TensorBoardColab() # Tensorboard


df10=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Isolation Forest/IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)
df2_10= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/2019 Dataframe/2019 10minutes IF 10 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)

X10_train= df10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_train=X10_train.values

y10_train= df10['Power_kW']
y10_train=y10_train.values

X10_test= df2_10[['WindSpeed_mps','AmbTemp_DegC','RotorSpeed_rpm','RotorSpeedAve','NacelleOrientation_Deg','MeasuredYawError','Pitch_Deg','WindSpeed1','WindSpeed2','WindSpeed3','GeneratorTemperature_DegC','GearBoxTemperature_DegC']]
X10_test=X10_test.values

y10_test= df2_10['Power_kW']
y10_test=y10_test.values




# scaling values for model


x_scale = MinMaxScaler()
y_scale = MinMaxScaler()

X10_train= x_scale.fit_transform(X10_train)
y10_train= y_scale.fit_transform(y10_train.reshape(-1,1))
X10_test=  x_scale.fit_transform(X10_test)
y10_test=  y_scale.fit_transform(y10_test.reshape(-1,1))


X10_train = X10_train.reshape((-1,1,12)) 
X10_test = X10_test.reshape((-1,1,12))







# creating model using Keras
model10 = Sequential()
model10.add(GRU(units=512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12)))
model10.add(GRU(units=256, return_sequences=True))
model10.add(GRU(units=256))
model10.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model10.compile(loss=['mse'], optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse']) 
model10.summary() 

history10=model10.fit(X10_train, y10_train, batch_size=256, epochs=25,validation_split=0.20, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])


score = model10.evaluate(X10_test, y10_test)
print('Score: {}'.format(score))



y10_predicted = model10.predict(X10_test)
y10_predicted = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_predicted)

y10_test = y_scale.inverse_transform(y10_test)

plt.plot( y10_predicted, label='Predicted')
plt.plot( y10_test, label='Measurements')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('/content/drive/My Drive/Figures/Power Prediction 10 Percent.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTMs(and also GRUs in spite of their lighter construction) are notorious for easily overfitting.

Reduce the number of units(the output size) in each of the layers(32(layer1)-64(layer2); you could also eliminate the last layer altogether.

The second of all, you are using the activation '`sigmoid`', but your loss function + metric is `mse`.

Ensure that your problem is either a `regression` or a `classification` one. If it is indeed a regression, then the activation function should be '`linear`' at the last step. If it is a classification one, you should change your loss_function to `binary_crossentropy` and your metric to '`accuracy`'.

Therefore, the plot displayed is just misleading for the moment. If you modify like I suggested and you still get such a train-val loss plot, then we can state for sure that you have an overfitting case.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time doing this so it is hard to keep along. From what I understood I should change units from first layer from 512 to 32 and from 256 to 64 in the second and also remove the dense layer? This is another question I have, does it matter if my loss and metric functions are the same? I've been reading about regression for a while and I undestood using dropout , L2 regularization and reducing the number of layers can decrease regression problems. I do not really know what is classification though. Also Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Well, in the case of regression ,it is okay to use mse both as a loss and as a metric.Indeed, using regularization techniques such as Dropout or L2 regularization can help you decrease overfitting problems. However, if you imagine a little bit, what would be better? To have 10 layers with many many neurons and use dropout on them? Or to have much fewer layers so that the overfitting problem from start is mitigated to a great extent? The solution is to gradually add layers if you observe that your model is not able to learn the training-set(underfitting). Gradually, not a huge model from start.

Comment: You are welcome, never forget that we were all beginners and all of us are here to learn and to help others learn!

Comment: Thank you very much I will start working on what you suggested now. Sorry to make sure I fully get it, Instead of use L2 or dropout, I should reduce the model to 1 layer and gradually keep adding layers? My last 2 very short questions are, am I using to many units in each layer? And for testing I'm using a different dataframe, and I chose validation_split=0.20, is 20% to much should I reduce it to 5%-10%?

Comment: Number of units in each layer should be a power of two(not necessarily). Use a layer of GRU (32 units) and add layers incrementally. After every small modification that you make on your network(new layers/number of neurons) test and see how it behaves during the training process. The train-validation split depends on the amount of your dataset. If you have a very small dataset, a split of 66%---train, 33%---val is acceptable. If you have a very big dataset(hundreds of thousands of examples), even a split of 95% train 5% val is good.So it really depends on the number of samples in your dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll start over with one layer and 32 units and gradually add layer/units till the models becomes fit. As for my dataset it has 13 columns and 10million rows so it is quite large? and I've read just an hour ago for large datasets 5%-10% for validation_split is quite enough. I'm extreeeemly sorry, if I do the above and the model becomes fit, do I change the activation function to `linear` and loss to `binary_crossentropy` or leave it as it is?

Comment: If you need to predict a real value (a number) you need to change the activation to 'linear' and let the other parameters exactly as they are in model.fit. If you need to predict a category(yes/no, 1/0), you need to use binary_crossentropy(loss_function) + 'sigmoid' activation and 'accuracy' as a metric.

Comment: However, as far as I see, you want to predict the power consumption in kW. So in your case you would only need to change activation = 'linear'.

Comment: Yes the purpose of all of this is try to predict power output in a year. So 95% training, 5% validation, loss and metrics as `mse` , optimizer as `adam` and activation as `linear`. Yet again I'm extremely thankful for your advice.

Comment: Thank you very much! working on it now, hope you have a great day.

Comment: Good luck, have a great day.